# Flutter: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe with pushNamedAndRemoveUntil

Tags: flutter

This happens on second line, if I comment it out everything is fine:

```
login(BuildContext context, bool fromExample, String method) async {
    final loading = new Loading();
    await loading.load(context, 'loads_logging_in'.tr);

switch (method) {
  case "Facebook":
    await authService.facebookSignIn(context);
    break;
  case "Google":
    await authService.googleSignIn(context);
    break;
  case "Apple":
    await authService.appleSignIn(context);
    break;
}

loading.cancel();
if (authService.getUser() == null) {
  return false;
}

Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/', (_) => false); // THIS LINE THROWS THE ERROR
}
```

And even if I **only** have that line I get exactly the same error:

> ======== Exception caught by widgets library ======================================================= The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree: Looking up a
> deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
>
> At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer
> stable.
>
> To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a
> reference to the ancestor by calling
> dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's
> didChangeDependencies() method.
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup. (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3864:9)
> #1      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3878:6)
> #2      Element.getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3905:12)
> #3      Provider._inheritedElementOf (package:provider/src/provider.dart:327:34)
> #4      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:284:30) ...

Replacing that line with `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/');` fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

The error was related with one of the providers having this on the default page I was redirecting to:

```
@override
void dispose() {
     Provider.of<AdState>(context, listen: false).getInterstitial()?.dispose();
     super.dispose();
}
```